# What sort order does couchdb use internally?

Tags: sorting, mapreduce, couchdb

I'm unable to find a good answer of how couchdb determines it's sort order in views. I thought it would be in ASCII order or be similar to javascript's sort function which converts everything to UTF-16 strings and compares based off of their byte values. However, I was a bit shocked to find that with the following view:

```
(doc) => {
  emit("a",null)
  emit("b",null)
  emit("A",null)
  emit("B",null)
}
```

the keys are not sorted `["A","B","a","b"]` as what Array.prototype.sort produces but rather `["a","A","b","B"]`. What is the implementation of the sort order that couchdb uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained thoroughly in the CouchDB documentation [3.2.2.5. Collation Specification](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/collation.html?highlight=collation#collation-specification)

> Comparison of strings is done using ICU which implements the Unicode Collation Algorithm, giving a dictionary sorting of keys. **This can give surprising results if you were expecting ASCII ordering**.

<sup>*Emphasis mine*</sup>

A thorough read of that section should give anyone a solid grasp of the collation rules.